# Express res.cookie and res.redirect not working correctly

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, response

I want to redirect with cookie to my frontend. So my code snipped like that:

```
const token = jwt.sign(access_info.data, config.jwtSecret);

console.log(token);

res.cookie("session_token", token, { maxAge: 900000 })
res.redirect("https://<myFrontend>.herokuapp.com/#/")
```

So its redirect to ***https:// < my Frontend > .herokuapp.com/#/*** successfully.
But When I check cookie on browser, There is no cookie.

Also console.log(token); output is

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.SeTN0KSq7MCGSyPrk8tbOPRT-EHVXPxNhDx4e9rdxbE
```

Why Im Getting this problem and How can I solve this? Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're checking your cookies from an area where all are listed, it's a possibility the cookie is being saved but you are in the wrong place to see it.
For example, a cookie saved on site1.com will not be shown on site2.com's storage tab in inspect element.

I've ran your code and the cookie is appearing when I check my cookies from localhost:3030 (my express API) but not on the site where it redirects :)

If you can see your cookies from, let's say, the browsers settings, then it's a problem with Express.

Also, you can shorten your code by just doing:

```
res.cookie("session_token", token, { maxAge: 900000 }).redirect("https://your_frontend.herokuapp.com/#/")
```